# Why is the C++ STL set container's count() method thus named?

Tags: c++, stl, naming-conventions, naming

What it really checks for is contains() and not the count of the number of occurrences, right? Duplicates are not permitted either so wouldn't contains() be a better name than count()?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit confusing since set::count() actually does the job of `contains`. Probably for historical reasons.

Comment: I think it's to match the [`multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) interface, where there can be duplicates (and thus `count()` can return >1). Not positive though.

Comment: Blah blah consistency it is a stupid name!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's to make it consistent with other container classes, given that one of the great aspects of polymorphism is to be able to treat different classes with the same API.

It *does* actually return the count. The fact that the count can only be zero or one for a set does not change that aspect.

It's not *fundamentally* different to a collection object that only allows two things of each "value" at the same time. In that case, it would return the count of zero, one or two, but it's still a count, the same as with a set.

The relevant part of the standard that requires this is `C++11 23.2.4` which talks about the associative containers `set`, `multiset`, `map` and `multimap`. Table 102 contains the requirements for these associative containers over and above the requirements for "regular" containers, and the bit for `count` is paraphrased below:

> `size_type a.count(k)` - returns the number of elements with key equivalent to `k`. Complexity is `log(a.size()) + a.count(k)`.

Comment: What does `Complexity is log(a.size()) + a.count(k)` mean? It seems recursive :)

Comment: @Cade, I was worried for a bit that I'd mis-transcribed it but no. It's not *actually* recursive since there is nothing in the function calling `a.count(k)` to calculate the complexity - it's simply stating that the complexity of the function is affected by the number of elements that match the key.

Answer (score 4):

All associative containers must meet the requirements listed in *§23.2.4/8 Table 102 - Associative container requirements*. One of these is that they implement `a.count(k)` which then

> returns the number of elements with key equivalent to k

So the reason is to have a consistent interface between all associative containers. For instance, this uniformity will be very important when writing generic function templates that must work with any associative container.

Answer (score -2):

It's a standard operation on containers that returns the number of matching elements.  In things like lists, this makes perfect sense.  It just so happens that on a set, there can only be one occurrence of an element and therefore `count` can never return a value greater than 1.

Comment: "In things like lists, this makes perfect sense." But std::list has no count method.

Comment: You're right.  I was really just handwaving in my attempt to name another container type, not specifically in the STL; rather, just *any* type that could conceivably have a `count` method.  @paxdiablo mentioned plenty of specific containers that *do* have a count method.