# What is std::set::equal_range for?

Tags: c++, stl

Since `std::set` cannot contain duplicate elements and is always sorted, `std::set::equal_range` will always return the range that has either none or 1 element. Technically, yes, that's still a *range*, but what is the purpose of this algorithm? For `std::set` it seems pretty unnecessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm only guessing. But, [like `count()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16534996/560648), it has some value when you're in a template and don't want to have to determine whether you're operating on a `std::set` or some other associative container.

Basically, it's for consistency. The function does perform as advertised, it's just that yes it has questionable use *versus* something like `find()` if you take it in isolation. It does potentially save you one manual iterator increment if you really do want a half-open range out of the box though. :P

Answer (score 9):

All of the associative containers support `equal_range`, which means you can write generic code which accepts a `set`, `multiset`, `map` or `multimap` and it will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider std::multiset. Despite practically identical in interface, it can contain equal_ranges of higher lengths.