# std::set - what's the purpose of count?

Tags: c++, stl, set

About `std::set` taken from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of
>   **unique objects** of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison
>   function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have
>   logarithmic complexity. Sets are usually implemented as red-black
>   trees.

As the question says, what's the purpose of `std::set<Key,Compare,Allocator>::count` method, [which](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/count):

> Returns the number of elements with key that compares equivalent to
>   the specified argument, **which is either 1 or 0 since this container**
>   **does not allow duplicates**.

What's the use of this, when `std::set` already has a method  `std::set<Key,Compare,Allocator>::find` which does the same thing.

Why this redundancy? Is it included just for the sake of completeness?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534931/why-is-the-c-stl-set-containers-count-method-thus-named

Comment: `find` doesn't do the same thing as `count`. `find` finds and return an iterator to the element in the container, `count` gives you a count of the number of times the element exists inside the container (which for a `std::set` is either `0` or `1` but for `std::multiset` could return more).

Answer (score 0):

It's used to be compatible with other STL containers like multiset.

Comment: @john Yes, you're right. I've just confused by QSet in Qt framework. I'll edit my answer right now. Thanks.